# Manually adding books to Nook App on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ebook

I need to "side load" a number of eBooks (mostly `epub` and `PDF`) into the Nook App on my iPad and iPhone.  This is something I am able to do with my dedicated Nook eReader like the Nook HD or the Glowlight (not the Samsung tablets). To add books, you simply connected it with a USB cable which then made the Nook look like a USB storage device to the Mac (or Windows machine) and you simply copied the files over.

For the record, I use [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/) to manage my personal library and to handle the file syncing to the Nook device.  As long as the device appeared as USB storage, it would handle (copy) it.

> ...calibre can directly connect to all the major (and most of the minor) e-book reading devices, smarthphones, tablets, etc. In addition, using the Connect to folder function you can use it with any e-book reader that exports itself as a USB disk.

<sup>Source:  [Calibre FAQ](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/faq.html#how-do-i-use-calibre-with-my-ipad-iphone-ipod-touch)</sup>

This isn't possible on an iOS device as it doesn't show up as a USB storage device.  How can I manually add my personal eBooks to my Nook App on my iPad, iPod, and/or iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nook App isn't very intuitive when it comes to telling you how to sideload books onto your iOS device, however it is possible.  Unfortunately, it's not as simple as just hooking up the device via USB and letting Calibre handle it.  There are two methods:

- Via USB (cable) and iTunes
- Downloaded from shared site

## USB Cable & iTunes

It's fairly easy to drag and drop via iTunes.

1. Connect your iOS device
2. Under *File Sharing*
3. Drag and drop your eBooks to the *Nook* folder

[image: Nook iTunes Location]

## Downloaded onto iOS device

This requires the [Files App](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/files/id1232058109) from Apple to access the folders on the iOS device

1. Download the eBook using your browser (Firefox shown here)
2. Go into the *Downloads* directory
3. Long press the file to bring up the context menu and select *Move*
4. Select the *Nook* directory
5. Press *Move*

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]