# iOS Shortcuts App - move or copy files

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app

I’ve been experimenting with the Shortcuts App on my iPad and iPhone (iPadOS 13 and iOS 13 respectively) and can’t  seem to find a way to move or copy a file from one directory to another.

This is related to my question [Manually adding books to Nook App on iPad](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/375594/119271) where in order to “side load“ eBooks to the Nook app, you have to manually move/copy the file from the `Downloads` folder to the `Nook` folder.  I’m doing this manually at the moment using the Files App, but I’d like to automate it with a shortcut.

While the immediate need is for the Nook, I have many other file moving tasks I’d like to automate like moving things to Synology NAS or files from iCloud to OneDrive (and vice versa)

Is there a way to do this with Shortcuts or is it simply not possible and I’m just missing it?

Comment: There are actions to get and save files, can't they be combined somehow?

Comment: I know I can download a file with a URL, but that goes to the Downloads folder.  I’m not familiar with the Save action.  I’ll have to look again.

Comment: It's called "Datei abrufen" in German (probably "Get File" or similar), you can either specify a path or open the file picker with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I was able to solve this issue with the following Shortcut…

[image: Share to Nook App Shortcut]

Basically, instead of copying and pasting files from one location to another, all is shared to the shortcut. The shortcut directories, allowing it to side load to the Nook application directory.

It plays a sound to followed by a notification banner, to provide feedback, that the file has been moved successfully.

Download the Shortcut [Send to Nook App](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/3c056169b2da4f93ab22c132a806c6de)